# Django 2.0.6 development server crashes on external connection

Tags: django

I've got some problems with the development server of Django 2.0.6.

It keeps running until I try to connect to it from another client, then it crashes immediately. `DEBUG = True` is set in the settings.py

Im using `Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)`

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 11, 2018 - 14:32:19
Django version 2.0.6, using settings 'bidm_django.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

---

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.29.0.178', 61797)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/srojek/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

**pip freeze**

```
Django==2.0.6
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2018.4
```

While it works fine locally on a windows machine using the pyCharm IDE it crashes on the linux machine.

Comment: What HTTP client are you using to access your application?

Comment: I tried Firefox ESR 52.7.3 (32-Bit) and Chrome Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-Bit)